# Maven built Hadoop rpms have no files in them

Tags: maven, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, rpmbuild

I am trying to build an HDP 3.1.4 cluster by replacing the Cloudera provided HDFS and YARN rpms wit the Apache Hadoop.
For the same, I am building the Hadoop 3.1.1 rpms using the maven method with the below command which completes successfully.

```
`mvn -B clean install rpm:rpm -DnewVersion=3.1.1  -DskipTests`
```

However, when I list the files in rpms using rpm -qlp, it says "contains no files"

```
rpm -qlp hadoop-main-3.1.1-1.noarch.rpm
(contains no files)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Cloudera actually tests and patches Hadoop with the rest of their components before they publish releases. I don't think grabbing Hadoop from source will be a good idea